# What is the texture of grilled swordfish?

Tags: fish, grilling

Purchased and grilled swordfish steaks, as usual, but the texture was very gelatinous(squishy) and raw feeling, though the color was opaque after cooking. Taste was bland and rubbery. The fish was marked Fresh, as opposed to the usual "previously frozen"
What is wrong?

Comment: To what degree did you cook it?

Comment: Cooked the swordfish @ 500degrees F on a gas grill 4-5 min. Ea. side..
It tasted maybe overdone,but the texture seemed a little rare. We have cooked Swordfish this way many times, with good results. Usually if overdone it tastes dry, this did not.

Comment: This fish was marked Fresh as opposed to "previously frozen" is that why? But shouldn't it taste better?

Comment: Hello Penny, if you use the device from which you asked your original question, you will be able to edit your own question. If you cannot do that, the system will not know it is your question, unless you registered. In this case, you should still be able to suggest an edit. This keeps the space below free for solutions only. I now converted your additions to comments (you can also leave those on your own question, or answers to it, until you get some reputation for using them everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

You may have purchased mislabeled fish. Unfortunately, this is a real problem, alas!  (So at least the texture issue might well not have been your doing.)

Answer (score 1):

You likely got old "fresh" fish. Fish contains protein-digestive enzymes that over time create a mushy texture. With frozen fish this is not a problem, as the enzymes are not active. Some kinds of fish and shellfish are very prone to this problem due to the high amount of enzymes in them, this is true for example for Pollack, Whiting, Lobster or Herring. They can turn out mushy even if they are really fresh. As far as I know, Swordfish does not belong to this category, so it is likely that the fish spent too much time in an inadequately cooled state (maybe already on the ship).

Answer (score 1):

Grilled swordfish is often referred to as being "steak like" in its texture. I agree with the others that your fish was probably not so fresh.